# Dragging a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, frame, uigesturerecognizer

I am using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to allow my `UITableView` to be dragged around. I have currently set it so that the `UITableView` cannot be dragged past `0` or half its width. But now, its frame is set to 0 when I try and drag the `UITableView` back to 0 from an origin of greater than 0. How can I prevent this and allow dragging of the `UITableView` back to 0? I have tried the following, but I can't quite find out why the outlined code is causing this.

```
- (void) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) pan {

    CGPoint point = [pan translationInView:_tableView];

    CGRect frame = [_tableView frame];

    if (point.x <= _tableView.frame.size.width / 2) {
        frame.origin.x = point.x;
    }

    NSLog(@"%f : %f", frame.origin.x, _tableView.frame.origin.x);
    //outline begin!
    if (frame.origin.x < 0 && _tableView.frame.origin.x >= 0) {
        frame.origin.x = 0;
    }
    //outline end!
    isFilterViewShowing = frame.origin.x > 0;

    [_tableView setFrame:frame];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the prettiest code, but that is working in the simulator.
For this code to work you need to add an instance variable.
This code may not behave exactly as you want it, because it's keeping track of "negative" x position, so you get some "threshold" effect that you may not want depending on you design choice.

```
- (void) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) pan {

if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    //  cache the starting point of your tableView in an instance variable
    xStarter = _tableView.frame.origin.x;
}

// What is the translation
CGPoint translation = [pan translationInView:self.tableView];
//  Where does it get us
CGFloat newX = xStarter + translation.x;

CGFloat xLimit = self.tableView.superview.bounds.size.width / 2;

if (newX >= 0.0f && newX <= xLimit)
{
    //  newX is good, don't touch it
}
else if (newX < 0)
{
    newX = 0;
}
else if (newX > xLimit)
{
    newX = xLimit;
}

CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
frame.origin.x = newX;

[_tableView setFrame:frame];

if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    //  reset your starter cache
    xStarter = 0;
}
}
```

---

Have you notice how `[pan translationInView:aView];` is returning the offset of the `pan gesture` and not the position of the finger on the screen.
That is why your code don't work as you expect.

Comment: That didn't actually help, I tried using the superView, but no touches were found. Can you apprehend why my code isn't working?

Comment: don't seek for touch in your superView, have the `pan` return the translation CGPoint in the superView's coordinate system.

Comment: can you give an example please?

Comment: ok, well I am still getting the error, do you have an answer to my problem in the OP?

Comment: Its the error outlined in the OP. I am unable to swipe the table back towards the left as its origin.x is immediately set to 0 having already swiped it to the right. Here is a sample of the error: http://cl.ly/3M2O0Q2P2E1V3G3N1v1k

Comment: Works brilliantly, thanks a lot! I had just coded this and it seemed to work, but not perfectly unlike yours - https://gist.github.com/1434371

Comment: @max_ my solution is not perfect, as I said there is a flaw in it, that you will probably want to fixe.

Comment: If you apply the pan gesture to the tableView the scrolling does not work. Do you know of any way around this?